# How to keep tab key event in its own div without leaving it

Tags: html

I am running into an issue with the tab key when I am navigating through controls, such as a grid. Once I get to the last column and click tab again, the whole layout goes off..
Here is how it looks while navigating through a grid
[image]

and here it looks after I tab again after the last column

[image]

This also happens if i am tabbing through a series of inputs, once it gets to the last input and i click tab again, then the whole layout ends up doing the same as the 2nd image, when it should just circle back to the first input from where i started

I ran

```
$('div').attr('tabindex', '-1')
```

and thought maybe this would help and it hasn't. I have no idea on how to keep the tab in its own div

Comment: I found the culprit, there was a div deep in the html that should have been there, still need to know how to keep the tab key in its own div though and not letting it out

Comment: Listen for the keydown event and when it's the tab key that was pressed call `event.preventDefault()`